# List Items moving or disappearing when scrolled out of screen

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

I have a Xamarin Forms Application for Android and IOS. When I open one of the larger lists on Android it looks fine when it is loaded. When I now scroll down however and up again on some entries the images are moved or disappeared at all.

Before:
[image]

After:

[image]

The list is defined with this XAML:

```
            <ListView x:Name="PaymentList"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DailyList}"
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      CachingStrategy="RecycleElementAndDataTemplate"
                      IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                      SeparatorVisibility="None">

                <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Key}"
                                  TextColor="{DynamicResource HeaderColor}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Clicked="EditPayment" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                          Text="{Binding Resources[EditLabel]}" />
                                <MenuItem Clicked="DeletePayment" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                          Text="{Binding Resources[DeleteLabel]}"
                                          IsDestructive="True" />
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <controls:CardView Margin="{StaticResource SmallLeftRightBottomMargin}" Style="{StaticResource ListItemStyle}">
                                <StackLayout Spacing="0"
                                             Margin="{StaticResource DefaultListItemsMargin}">
                                    <Grid>

                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                                               Text="{Binding Category.Name}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource ListItemHeaderSmallStyle}" />

                                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                               Style="{StaticResource SmallTextStyle}"
                                               Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource PaymentAmountConverter}}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid >

                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Label Grid.Column="0"
                                           Text="{Binding Note}" 
                                           Style="{StaticResource DeemphasizedSmallLabelStyle}" />

                                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                                            <Image HeightRequest="15"
                                                   WidthRequest="15"
                                                   IsVisible="{Binding IsTransfer}" >
                                                <Image.Source>
                                                    <FontImageSource
                                                        Glyph="{StaticResource Transfer}"
                                                        FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialFontFamily}"
                                                        Color="{DynamicResource PrimaryFontColor}" />
                                                </Image.Source>
                                            </Image>

                                            <Image HeightRequest="15"
                                                   WidthRequest="15"
                                                   IsVisible="{Binding IsRecurring}" >
                                                <Image.Source>
                                                    <FontImageSource
                                                        Glyph="{StaticResource Recurring}"
                                                        FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialFontFamily}"
                                                        Color="{DynamicResource PrimaryFontColor}" />
                                                </Image.Source>
                                            </Image>

                                            <Image HeightRequest="15"
                                                   WidthRequest="15"
                                                   IsVisible="{Binding IsCleared}">
                                                <Image.Source>
                                                    <FontImageSource
                                                        Glyph="{StaticResource Cleared}"
                                                        FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialFontFamily}"
                                                        Color="{DynamicResource PrimaryFontColor}" />
                                                </Image.Source>
                                            </Image>

                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </controls:CardView>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

I also tried it with another caching mode. But with retain element the elements on scrolling are just empty.

[image]

The list has around 130 items.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use **FFImageLoading** to render the images correctly,I guess that **FFImageLoading** will solved you issue.

Install **Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms** by NuGet packages...

Here is the detailed info about using FFimageLoading.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-ffimageloading-app2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried that out. Unfortunately it is even worse that way. ^^

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that when I change `HasUnevenRows="True"` to False (the default value) and set a fix RowHeight, I can use `CachingStrategy="RetainElement"` without having emtpy elements. That way the issue seems to not occur anymore.

Comment: I'm trying it but not working it is working when replacing CachingStrategy="RetainElement" with CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"